# Handling KeyError in the test for REST API request

Tags: python, rest, testing, automated-tests

I have a test where I'm sending a request for creating data and I'm returning:

```
return response, response.json()
```

In the test I'm expecting to see an error, as I'm creating data with invalid format, but I get KeyError on assert as data was created successfully. 
This:

```
assert_true(response[1]['error']['code'] == 400, "Incorrect status code received in the response body.")
```

raises

```
KeyError: '\'error\
```

That is because I get this in `response[1]`:

```
{'addResults': [{'objectId': 143, 'uniqueId': 143, 'globalId': None, 'success': True}], 'updateResults': [], 'deleteResults': []}
```

But I'm expecting to get this:

```
{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid token.', 'details': ['Invalid token.']}}
```

I can see clearly on which line my test failed, but I'm wondering if there is a better way of handling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dictionary '.get()' method instead of square brackets

```
assert_true(response[1].get('error', {}).get('code') == 400, "Incorrect status code received in the response body.")
```

The second parameter is a default value to be returned if the key does not exist. No second parameter defaults to None. Using an empty dict there allows you to chain them together.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about this before I posted a question, I went with it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```py
try:
   return response, response.json()
except KeyError:
   pass
```

That should minimize the error and you can continue with the script

Comment: Thanks but no, response is returned correctly, but json of the response just doesn't contain 'error' key, as request succeeded in creating data.

Comment: I've added more info to the question for clarity.